# CSV delimiter messed up when exporting many rows without enclosure

Tags: php, laravel, csv, quoting, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel Excel and it’s fine when exporting around 1k rows without enclosure. I'm using queue export and CSV delimiter starting mess up when exporting above 4k rows. Rows and Headings contain space. I'm using Query Builder. I want to export my .csv file without enclosure.

**Exported CSV File (Without Enclosure)**

There can be lots of Column Headings and Rows.

For example

Around 1k rows

```
Full Name,First Name,Last Name,Location,Email Address
John Smith Doe,John Smith,Doe,15 Street,johndoe@example.com
Mary Chris Brown,Mary Chris,Brown,15 Aveune,mary@mail.com
```

Above 4k rows

```
Full,Name,First,Name,Last,Name,Location,Email,Address
John,Smith,Doe,John,Smith,Doe,15,Street,johndoe@example.com,,,,,
Mary,Chris,Brown,Mary,Chris,Brown,15,Aveune,mary@mail.com,,,,,,,
```

Note: Space disappears and additional commas appear at the end of the rows

**Additional Information**

ReportsController

```php
class ReportsController extends Controller 
{
    public function export() 
    {
        (new ReportsExport)->queue('reports.csv');

        return response()->json([
               'download_link' => Storage::url('reports.csv')
        ]);
    }
}
```

ReportsExport

```php
class ReportsExport implements FromQuery, WithMapping, WithHeadings, WithCustomCsvSettings
{
    use Exportable;

    public function query() 
    {
        // Actually, I'm performing complex query behind the scenes
        // and I do not use "get()" as the doc says...
        $record = DB::table('reports')->orderBy('id', 'asc');

        return $record;
    }

    public function map($record): array
    {
        return [
            $record->column_1,
            ...
        ];
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            "Heading 1"
            ...
        ];
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'enclosure' => ''  // no enclosure
        ];
    }
}
```

**Versions**

- PHP version: 7.3.18
- Laravel version: 7.13.0
- Package version: 3.1